# Laravel Eloquent model with multiple relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a requirement to build a task object that can have multiple relations

```
A Task can have these relations (note even though some say required they are actually optional)

-- itemA_required // this can have many entries
-- itemA_optional // this can have many entries
-- itemB_required // this can have many entries
-- itemB_optional // this can have many entries
-- itemC_required // this can have many entries
-- itemC_optional // this can have many entries
-- itemD_required // this can have many entries
-- itemD_optional // this can have many entries
```

I then have tables like this

```
task -- id|name|description

itemA -- id|name|description
itemB -- id|name|description
itemC -- id|name|description
itemD -- id|name|description

task_itemA_required  -- id|task_id| itema_id
task_itemA_optional  -- id|task_id| itema_id

task_itemB_required  -- id|task_id| itemb_id
task_itemB_optional  -- id|task_id| itemb_id

task_itemC_required  -- id|task_id| itemc_id
task_itemC_optional  -- id|task_id| itemc_id

task_itemD_required  -- id|task_id| itemd_id
task_itemD_optional  -- id|task_id| itemd_id
```

And models to go with this

```
task
itemA
itemB
itemC
itemD
task_itemA_required
task_itemA_optional
task_itemB_required
task_itemB_optional
task_itemC_required
task_itemC_optional
task_itemD_required
task_itemD_optional
```

The Task model has methods like this

```
public function ItemARequired()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Models\ItemARequired');
}
public function ItemAOptional()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Models\ItemAOptional');
}
```

My questions are

Is this the best way to go about doing this? The large number of model doesn't make this seem very 'Eloquent'.

If this is correct way to go about this, how do I query for a task so it returns all of the relations and the id, name and description that goes with the related item? Does this require using something like this for each kind of relation in the Task model? I've tried variations of this and haven't gotten it to work. I guess I don't really understand the eloquent way of doing this.

```
public function ItemARequired()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\ItemA', 'App\task_itemA_required');
}
```

Hope what I have written here makes sense.

Comment: is that possible in your task_itemA, you add boolean field `required`? so your table could look like this `task_itemA  -- id|task_id| itema_id|required` and task and itemA have `belongsToMany` eloquent relationship